# Spring Boot HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect() not working from iOS

Tags: java, ios, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller in my Spring Boot app that simple makes a redirection:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/return", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Transactional
    public void returnData(UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String transactionState=request.getParameter("state");
        String billCode=request.getParameter("bill");
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("extra2"));
        String description=removeAccents(request.getParameter("extra2").replace("%", " "));
        String billValue=request.getParameter("value");
        String paymentMethod=getPaymentMethodName(request.getParameter("method"));


        response.sendRedirect(hostname+"/payment_resume?state="+ transactionState
                +"&"+"billCode="+billCode
                +"&"+"description="+description
                +"&"+"billValue="+billValue
                +"&"+"paymentMethod="+paymentMethod);
        return;
    }
```

the problem is that this does not work in mobile safari ... no redirection is made. On the other hand, in the desktop versions (Safari / Chrome) and in Android devices (Chrome mobile) works perfectly ... it does the redirection.My question is to what this fact is, and what should I do to solve this problem.

Many thanks!

Comment: Just wondering if you can see the new redirect URL in the browser address field while accessing it from the safari mobile browser

Comment: Could you test without hostname, means response.sendRedirect("/payment_resume?... else could print the hostname to see how it looks like ?

Comment: @TinyOS hostname: http://localhost:4200/payment_resume?...